# How to make a quiz program in java not return the booleans `true` or `false`

Tags: java, boolean

I am currently making a six question quiz (2 from `AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion()`, 2 from `FillInQuestion()`, and 2 from `NumericQuestion()`) using the code below. My problem is that I need to be able to print `"Correct answer :)"` or `"Wrong answer :("` without also printing the booleans `true` or `false`. I cannot edit Question.java or ChoiceQuestion.java, so the solution is not as simple as changing the output of the parent function `public boolean CheckAnswer()` within Question.java to be void. I have listed my code below. I apologize for the amount of code this question contains, but it is necessary to understand the problem. Thank you for your time.

Question.java:

```
/**
 This class makes a question with a text and an answer.
 */
public class Question
{
    private String text;
    private String answer;

    /**
     Constructs a question with empty question and answer.
     */
    public Question()
    {
        text = "";
        answer = "";
    }

    /**
     Sets the question text.
     @param questionText the text of this question
     */
    public void setText(String questionText)
    {
        text = questionText;
    }

    /**
     Sets the answer for this question.
     @param correctResponse the answer
     */
    public void setAnswer(String correctResponse)
    {
        answer = correctResponse;
    }

    /**
     Checks a given response for correctness.
     @param response the response to check
     @return true if the response was correct, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean checkAnswer(String response)
    {
        return response.equals(answer);
    }

    /**
     Displays this question.
     */
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

ChoiceQuestion.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
A question with multiple choices.
*/
public class ChoiceQuestion extends Question
{
    private ArrayList<String> choices;

    /**
    Constructs a choice question with no choices.
    */
    public ChoiceQuestion()
    {
        choices = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
    Adds an answer choice to this question.
    @param choice the choice to add
    @param correct true if this is the correct choice, false otherwise
    */
    public void addChoice(String choice, boolean correct)
    {
        choices.add(choice);
        if (correct) 
        {
            // Convert choices.size() to string
            String choiceString = "" + choices.size();
            setAnswer(choiceString);
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        // Display the question text
        super.display();
        // Display the answer choices
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++)
        {
            int choiceNumber = i + 1;
            System.out.println(choiceNumber + ": " + choices.get(i));     
        }
    }
}
```

AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion.java:

```
public class AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion extends Question {
    private String answer;
    private String text;
    private boolean condition = false;
    //Constructs a question with empty question and answer.
    public AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion(){
      answer = "";
      text = "";
    }

    public void setText(String questionText){
      text = questionText;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String correctResponse){
      answer = correctResponse;
    }

    public boolean checkAnswer(String response){
      if(answer.contains(response)){
        condition = true;
        QuestionsApp.score += 3;
        System.out.println("Correct answer :)");
        }
        else{
          condition = false;
          System.out.println("Wrong answer :(");
        }
        return condition;
    }

    public void display(){
      System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

FillInQuestion.java:

```
public class FillInQuestion extends Question{
    private String answer;
    private String text;
    private boolean condition = false;
    //Constructs a question with empty question and answer.
    public FillInQuestion(){
      answer = "";
      text = "";
    }

    public void setAnswer(String correctAnswer){
      answer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public void setText(String questionText){
      text = questionText;
      text = text.replaceAll("\\_.*?\\_", "____");
    }

    public boolean checkAnswer(String response){
      if(answer.contains(response)){
        condition = true;
        QuestionsApp.score += 2;
        System.out.println("Correct answer :)");
        }
        else{
          condition = false;
          System.out.println("Wrong answer :(");
        }
        return condition;
    }

    public void display(){
      System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```

NumericQuestion.java:

```
public class NumericQuestion extends Question{

    private final double different_amount = 0.01;
    private double answer;
    private boolean condition = false;

    public NumericQuestion(){
      answer = 0;
    }

    public void setAnswer(double correctResponse){
      answer = correctResponse;
    }

    public boolean checkAnswer(double response){
      if(Math.abs(answer - response) < different_amount || Math.abs(response - answer) < different_amount){
        QuestionsApp.score += 1;
        System.out.println("Correct Answer :)");
        condition = true;
        }
        else{
          condition = false;
          System.out.println("Wrong Answer :(");
        }
          return condition;
        }
    }
```

QuestionsApp.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuestionsApp{

  public static int score;
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Question one = new Question();
    one.setText("Who was the inventor of Java?");
    one.setAnswer("James Gosling");

    ChoiceQuestion two = new ChoiceQuestion();
    two.setText("In which country was the inventor of Java born?");
    two.addChoice("Australia", false);
    two.addChoice("Canada", true);
    two.addChoice("Denmark", false);
    two.addChoice("United States", false);

    NumericQuestion three = new NumericQuestion();
    three.setText("What is the value of PI to the nearest thousandth?");
    three.setAnswer("3.141");

    NumericQuestion four = new NumericQuestion();
    four.setText("What is the value of the Euler's number to the nearest thousandth?");
    four.setAnswer("2.711");

    Question five = new FillInQuestion();
    five.setText("The inventor of Java was _James Gosling_");
    five.setAnswer("James Gosling");

    Question six = new FillInQuestion();
    six.setText("The inventor of Pascal was _Niklaus Wirth_");
    six.setAnswer("Niklaus Wirth");

    Question seven = new AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion();
    seven.setText("The inventor of Java lived in: \n1. Australia \n2. Canada \n3. Denmark \n4. United States \nNote, there may be several correct answers.");
    seven.setAnswer("1 2");

    Question eight = new AnyCorrectChoiceQuestion();
    eight.setText("The inventor of Pascal lived in:\n1. Australia \n2. Canada \n3. Denmark \n4. United States \n5. France \nNote, there may be several correct answers.");
    eight.setAnswer("1 4");

    ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
    list.add(three);
    list.add(four);
    list.add(five);
    list.add(six);
    list.add(seven);
    list.add(eight);

    for(Question questions : list){
      presentQuestion(questions);
      }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your score is " + QuestionsApp.score + " out of 12");
    System.out.println("Thank You!");

    }

    public static void presentQuestion(Question question)
    {
      question.display();
      System.out.print("Your answer: ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String response = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println(question.checkAnswer(response));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this post has so many downvotes besides due to the amount of code within the question? Or are all three downvotes because of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're printing out the `boolean` return from `checkAnswer`.  So you can't possibly expect any output other than the generic "true" or "false" you're getting.  If you want to print something different, you have to use that `boolean` result to select different courses of action that will result in different messages of your choosing being printed.

One way could be to use an `if` statement to select one of two output statements:

```
if (question.checkAnswer(response))
    System.out.println("You got it CORRECT!");
else
    System.out.println("Sorry, incorrect; better luck next time.");
```

Another way could be to use a single output statement, but use a ternary operator to select which string is used as the argument:

```
System.out.println(
   question.checkAnswer(response) 
       ? "You got it CORRECT!" 
       : "Sorry, incorrect; better luck next time"
);
```

These exact solutions aren't the only possibilities, but they illustrate the two basic ways of making an either/or decision in Java.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Kevin! I will make sure to use these two solutions in the future.

Comment: Yes, you certainly will :-)  And believe me when I say you won't have to "make sure to use" these techniques, either:  in fact, you will scarcely be able to _avoid_ using them.

Answer (score 0):

In your QuestionsApp.java, Change your last line to:

```
if(question.checkAnswer(response)) {
 System.out.println("Correct answer :)");
}
else {
 System.out.println("Wrong answer :(");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

move the display specific code into QuestionsApp.java.  This would also allow you to reuse your classes for different scenarios.  You're tying them to a specific output.  You may want to reuse in a web app.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.